# Why does Eclipse IDE show the output for this java program which contains error?

Tags: java, eclipse, abstract-class, abstract

When I try to run program.java in Eclipse IDE in spite of having an error, it shows the output in the console. But when I try to compile the same program using CMD, it throws a compilation error. I am learning and trying Abstract class. (I know we have to add abstract before class B) .

[program.java in Eclipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQDsE.jpg)

[compiling program.java in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fF7Ta.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Eclipse generate .class file if there is a syntax error in my Java source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18349168/why-does-eclipse-generate-class-file-if-there-is-a-syntax-error-in-my-java-sour)

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse IDE is caching the build of your program, so each time he does not compile fully again but only the changed source. Eclipse has this option that if you have an error while building, it will use an older build which compile so that you can execute it.

So i think that's the main issue.

Please, try to Clean all and then rebuild in Eclipse and see if it keeps running on it

For Eclipse you can find the rebuild option under Project > Clean and then select the project

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse uses its own compiler that allows incremental compilation, building the project even if you have errors, and a few other things. It automatically builds every time you save, so it may have a previous version of your file (that works) already compiled.

The `javac` you are using from the command line is probably the Oracle or OpenJDK version, which do not let you build projects when you have any errors in them.

As for your actual code, you should either mark `B` as `abstract`, or actually implement the abstract `display` method declared in `A`, since only abstract classes are allowed to have abstract methods.

Every time you attempt to run your project and it still has build errors, Eclipse should show you a message asking if you want to continue despite those errors (unless you tick the box saying you don't want to see the message again). I don't recommend running projects in Eclipse even when you have errors - the compiler complains for a reason.